# Extract ZIP in php, overwriting everything

Tags: php, zip, overwrite

I'm extracting server side .zip using this:

```
<?php
$unzip = shell_exec("unzip zipp1.zip");
?>
```

It's working fine, but it doesn't overwrite existing files (and I need it!).

Everything is in the same folder, chmod 777.

Can I add something to fix?
Tnx!

Comment: `-o` switch, when in doubt `man unzip`

Comment: Wow! It perfectly works!
Problem solved in less than 3 mins... you're great! :)
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use shell, you can write `unzip -o zipp1.zip`.

However, PHP has a library for working with Zip archives, called `ZipArchive`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

There you can `extractTo` which overwrites by default: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php

It's usually a good security practice to disable `shell_exec()`, so using PHP's libraries is recommended.

Comment: Also note, if your goal is to process a file inside the zip with PHP, then you don't even need to extract the file. You can read the file contents directly from PHP with the [zip stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php).